# :makestart fails when setting up DecompWorkspace in Minecraft Forge Gradle; multiple errors in openeing .zip files

Tags: gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

When setting up the Forge DecompWorkspace, it crashes when creating the :makestart. Any help? Below is my output when run.

Thanks.

P.S. I have tried running it with --refresh-dependencies, but still no luck. Also, Java 7 and its JDK are installed completely and correctly.

```
C:\Minecraft\1.7\Project>gradlew setupDevWorkspace --refresh-dependencies
****************************
 Powered By MCP:
 http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/
 Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r,
 R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs
 MCP Data version : unknown
****************************
:downloadClient SKIPPED
:downloadServer SKIPPED
:getVersionJson
:extractUserDev UP-TO-DATE
:mergeJars SKIPPED
:applyBinPatches SKIPPED
:downloadMcpTools SKIPPED
:extractMcpData UP-TO-DATE
:genSrgs SKIPPED
:deobfBinJar SKIPPED
:extractNatives UP-TO-DATE
:getAssetsIndex
:getAssets
:makeStart
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\tv.twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\c3cde57891b935d41b6680a9c5e1502
eeab76d86\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar; error in opening
zip file
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\aa9aae879af8eb378e22cfc64db56ec2c
a9a44d1\lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-linux.jar; error in opening zip file
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\2d12c83fdfbc04ecabf02c7bc8cc54d03
4f0daac\lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-osx.jar; error in opening zip file
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\17.0\9c6ef172e8de35fd8d4d8783e4821e57cdef7445\g
uava-17.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\90a3822c38ec8c996e84c16a3477ef6
32cbc87a3\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ant:javac] 5 errors
:makeStart FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':makeStart'.
> Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 10.551 secs

C:\Minecraft\1.7\Project>gradlew --refresh-dependencies setupDevWorkspace idea
****************************
 Powered By MCP:
 http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/
 Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r,
 R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs
 MCP Data version : unknown
****************************
:downloadClient SKIPPED
:downloadServer SKIPPED
:getVersionJson
:extractUserDev UP-TO-DATE
:mergeJars SKIPPED
:applyBinPatches SKIPPED
:downloadMcpTools SKIPPED
:extractMcpData UP-TO-DATE
:genSrgs SKIPPED
:deobfBinJar SKIPPED
:extractNatives UP-TO-DATE
:getAssetsIndex
:getAssets
:makeStart
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\tv.twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\c3cde57891b935d41b6680a9c5e1502
eeab76d86\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar; error in opening
zip file
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\aa9aae879af8eb378e22cfc64db56ec2c
a9a44d1\lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-linux.jar; error in opening zip file
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\2d12c83fdfbc04ecabf02c7bc8cc54d03
4f0daac\lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-osx.jar; error in opening zip file
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\17.0\9c6ef172e8de35fd8d4d8783e4821e57cdef7445\g
uava-17.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ant:javac] error: error reading C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\
files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\90a3822c38ec8c996e84c16a3477ef6
32cbc87a3\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ant:javac] 5 errors
:makeStart FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':makeStart'.
> Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 46.544 secs

C:\Minecraft\1.7\Project>
```

Comment: Does `OldPropertyMapSerializer.java` correctly `import` the `Properties` class? It looks like it might not, judging by the error message.

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I looked at it in a compiler, and the code is all there.

Comment: OK, now since you've changed the text of the question, it seems like the imports are likely correct.
Do try the --info or --debug flags if you haven't already.

Comment: Can you do `jar tvf C:\Users\redgames1234\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.3.290a3822c38ec8c996e84c16a3477ef632cbc87a3\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar`, to list the contents of that jar file?